# .NET core Entity Framework - escaping "@" character

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

**Intro**
I'm using the [PostreSQL JSON support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) which gives me a powerful API, but it contains some weird characters.
EF handles some of them (for example `->>`), but has problems with others (for example `@>`)

**Goal:**
Execute the following query as a raw query in the .net core EF:

```
SELECT * FROM todoitem WHERE "JsonPayload" @> '{"ListProp": [{"Name": "listProp1Name", "Value": "listProp1Value"}]}'
```

**Current situation**

```
string select = "SELECT * FROM todoitem";
string where = "WHERE \"JsonPayload\" @>";
string listQuery = "'{\"ListProp\": [{\"Name\": \"listProp1Name\", \"Value\": \"listProp1Value\"}]}'";

string query = $"{select} {where} {listQuery}";
Console.WriteLine(query);

var items = _context.TodoItems.FromSql(query).ToList();
```

Note: Please do not blame me for the string separation here. I was just narrowing down the problem. The output string is exactly the same as the one that I execute in the database (where it works).

**The problem**
Looks like the `@` character takes the blame, because it's being interpreted as a named parameter.
So the question is - how to escape it?

it is also possible, that brackets (`{` and `}`) are also going to be problematic, as they are used as variable indicators too. Please also write if you know how to escape them.

Obviously I tried googling around, but it seems it's not common to escape the `@` sign.

Stack Trace:
it's the same in both cases - when using `@>` and `@@>`.

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'dotnet_postgres_test.Models.TodoContext'.
      System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
         at System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError()
```

Comment: Have you tried with `@@`?

Comment: yup. also didn't work. gonna paste the stacktrace in the question.  
thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe that's not an exact answer, but you can use [dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net)

with dapper you can just write the following:

```
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

var items = connection
    .Query<TodoItem>(
        @"SELECT * FROM todoitem WHERE ""JsonPayload"" @> '{""ListProp"": [{""Name"": ""listProp1Name"", ""Value"": ""listProp1Value""}]}'")
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

base on [How to: Directly Execute SQL Queries | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-directly-execute-sql-queries#example-1) and [@ - C# Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

---

```
    var sql=@"SELECT * FROM todoitem WHERE ""JsonPayload"" @> '{""ListProp"": [{""Name"": ""listProp1Name"", ""Value"": ""listProp1Value""}]}'";

   var items  = _context.Database.SqlQuery<TodoItems>(sql).ToList();
```

Comment: looks like my `Database` is of different type, because it doens't have this method (or `ExecuteQuery` method that was mentioned in the first link). Maybe the resource that you linked is from the .NET Framework (not .NET Core) version?